# Problem with removing ListView's item with image from FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-futurebuilder

I am creating an application where there is a list of items in a ListView. Each item has a description and a photo.
Each item is downloaded by my api and the ListView builder generates a test widget "TestInternalWidget" for each item with a photo generated again by FutureBuilder. In a real application, the fetchPhoto method returns the Uint8list photo. For simulation purposes I simply return the url.
It works fine. However, there is a problem when deleting an item from the list. The element is removed, but the photo is not. For example:
I want to delete item 2: The description is deleted, but, the picture from item 2 jumps to item 3, etc.

**before removing item 2:**
[image]

**after removing item 2:**
[image]

I will be grateful for your help. I am using getx for state management, but I checked in standard configuration with setstate() and there was the same problem

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:camera_app/views/widgets/testwidget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'controllers/testcontroller.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TestController testController = Get.put(TestController());
    return GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'test',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black54),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xfffee6dc),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xfffff6f7),
          body: Obx(() => ListView.builder(
              cacheExtent: 100,
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              //physics : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: testController.albumList.length,
              itemExtent: 120,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                print("item build");
                return InkWell(
                    onDoubleTap: () {
                      testController.albumList.removeAt(index);
                    },
                    child: Obx(()=>  TestInternalWidget(testController.albumList[index]))
                );
              })
          )
      )
    );
  }

}
```

**testcontroller.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


//MODEL CLASS
class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
   String ? url;

   Album({
    required this.userId,
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.url
  });

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}

List<Album> AlbumFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Album>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Album.fromJson(x)));


class TestController extends GetxController {
  var albumList = <Album>[].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    print("init controller");
    fetchItems();
    super.onInit();
  }


  Future<void> fetchItems() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/'));

    List<Album> listAlbum;
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      listAlbum = AlbumFromJson(response.body);

      //Adding sample url for every item
      for(int i = 0; i< listAlbum.length; i++){
        listAlbum[i].url = 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=' + i.toString();
      }
      albumList.addAll(listAlbum);

    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load album');
    }
  }
  
}
```

**testwidget.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../controllers/testcontroller.dart';
class TestInternalWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  Album album;
  TestInternalWidget(this.album);

  @override
  TestInternalWidgetState createState() => TestInternalWidgetState();

}

class TestInternalWidgetState extends State<TestInternalWidget>
{
  Future<String?> fetchPhoto() async
  {
    //here for test I'm returning only string url, but in real Uint8List object from my backend api
    return widget.album.url;
  }
  late Future<String?> myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myFuture = fetchPhoto();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      print("internal widget build");
      return  Container(
          child:Column(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                future: myFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  String url = snapshot.data as String;
                  return snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null
                      ?
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 30.0,
                    backgroundImage:
                    NetworkImage(url),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  )
                   : CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
              Text(widget.album.title),
            ],
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
              color: Color(0xffE4CFC6)
          )
      );
    }

}
```

Comment: both of your images are the same!

Comment: @aminjafari-dev No. They are not the same

Comment: is it showing any error in console?

Comment: @PratulPant not showing any error. it looks like removing an item - TestInternalWidget has no effect on removing the child FutureBuilder widget, but only on the Text widget. And I realize that this doesn't happen if i remove item from end of the list. Then it works fine.

Comment: @PratulPant maybe it has something with reorder items in listview generated by ListView.builder

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Key` to the widgets you show in the ListView to help Flutter understand that the item at, say, index 2 is not the same as it was before. This [article](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d) explains it well.  Ideally you use an `ObjectKey` related to the contents of the item in your list. I'm a bit confused as to what is real versus test code in your code, but for example if each item you show has a unique URL then you could create the widget using `MyWidget(key: ObjectKey(item.url))` or with additional constructor fields as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. I tried before UniqueKey but it's not worked. With ObjectKey is ok. But now is another problem which which I was trying to avoid. Before, item fetchPhoto() in initState() was called only once for each item even if some element was removed. Now if I remove one element, every item is calling initState() again and fetching photo again. I am trying to do something like this  where, after removing an element, the remaining elements will not download the photo again, to make unnecessary requests.

Comment: The argument you pass with `ObjectKey` should be something that is unique to the contents of the widget in the list, independent of its position in the list, and the same over time. For example, the URL you used to download the photo, or a hash of the photo bytes. That way, the flutter build system knows that the underlying state of the widget with a photo has not changed, and can reuse the state when moving the picture to another location.